# please tell me the problem in this shell script ??it is not running the conditional statements....the results are displayed in unsub category only?

Tags: shell

```
for ((i=0;i<5;i++))
do
result=$(mysql -u' ' -p' ' -Ddb_bcore -h' ' -sNe "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM db_bcore.tb_subscriptions GROUP BY STATUS limit 1 offset $i;")
echo "$i"
if ["$i" == "0"];
then
echo "pending = $result"
elif ["$i" == "1"];
then
echo "active = $result"
elif ["$i" == "2"];
then
echo "lowbalance = $result"
elif ["$i" == "3"];
then
echo "expired = $result"
else
echo "unsub = $result"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these.

1. Instead of "==", use "=".
2. Put a  space between square brackets and comparators.

E.g.,
if [ "$i" = "0" ];

Hope it helps. Modified code here.

```
for ((i=0;i<5;i++))
do
result=$(mysql -u' ' -p' ' -Ddb_bcore -h' ' -sNe "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM db_bcore.tb_subscriptions GROUP BY STATUS limit 1 offset $i;")
echo "$i"
if [ "$i" = "0" ];
then
echo "pending = $result"
elif [ "$i" = "1" ];
then
echo "active = $result"
elif [ "$i" = "2" ];
then
echo "lowbalance = $result"
elif [ "$i" = "3" ];
then
echo "expired = $result"
else
echo "unsub = $result"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For your script it is better to use `case` structure:

```
for ((i=0;i<5;i++))
do
result=$(mysql -u' ' -p' ' -Ddb_bcore -h' ' -sNe "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM db_bcore.tb_subscriptions GROUP BY STATUS limit 1 offset $i;")
echo "$i"
case $i in 
0)
echo "pending = $result"
;;
1)
echo "active = $result"
;;
2)
echo "lowbalance = $result"
;;
3)
echo "expired = $result"
;;
*)
echo "unsub = $result"
;;
esac
```

Also add space around `[` and `]` . And when comparing numbers use `-eq`, not `=`